# Can monsters with a teleport ability grab enemies to teleport them both?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, teleportation

Some monsters have an Action/Legendary Action that allows them to teleport 120 feet. Using the [Balor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/balor) as an example:

> Teleport. The balor magically teleports, along with any equipment it
> is wearing or carrying, up to 120 feet to an unoccupied space it can
> see.

Could it grab an enemy and then teleport them both 120 feet away?

Comment: Actually, while I'm here: KayronMorthos, is there a particular concern you have with this interaction or possibility? Is this something that came up in a game, as part of some kind of planning, etc.? Having that context can often allow much better insight to help you with this.

Answer (score 33):

#### A teleportation feature allows a passenger only if it explicitly says so.

How else are you supposed to know you can bring someone along? To put it another way, *everything you need to know about Balor's teleport feature is contained in its description*.

Consider the spell *thunder step*:

> You can also teleport one willing creature of your size or smaller who is carrying gear up to its carrying capacity.

*Thunder step* explicitly states that you can bring a friend along. Since Balor's feature doesn't say another creature may come along, Balor's teleport feature is a solo trip (since other creatures are definitively not equipment).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127980/discussion-on-answer-by-thomas-markov-can-monsters-with-a-teleport-ability-grab).

Answer (score 17):

### No

But only in the specific case quoted.

There is no *general* rule on whether you can teleport with others and in what circumstances: some allow it, some don’t.

This one doesn’t. It explicitly says “The balor” and “any equipment it is wearing or carrying”. Another creature is not “equipment”.

Other abilities with different wording will have different results.

Comment: The problem with this interpretation is that it produces the obviously nonsense result that the balor can't teleport with loot as it isn't equipment.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Loot coming with you being mentioned in teleport descriptions seems to be more of a mistake/overlook than bringing a whole nother creature with you via teleportation. Misty step doesn't mention carrying equipment but I highly doubt it is meant to bring another creature with you. Dimension Door/Thunder Step though, go out of their way to describe it. Every spell that can bring someone with it, says it can.

Comment: @Jihelu I do agree, but for a different reason.  Creatures get saving throws against it, objects do not.

Comment: If the balor has already grappled an enemy creature, does the grappled creature go along for the ride?  (Or is that a different question?)

Comment: @LorenPechtel all adventurers would argue that loot *is* equipment

Answer (score 6):

No, as a general rule.

Teleport powers are one person, with equipment, and cannot carry other creatures unless specifically stated.  Some *do* specify that, such as Dimension Door that allows you to bring someone with you, or Thunder Step.  The Teleport *spell* lets you bring others along.  But any such spell or power that does not say you can carry others with you does not allow that.

Answer (score 5):

## No

First, spells and abilities can generally only do what they say. I've already seen the comments about how some argue about other spells leaving the teleporter naked, where I'd just call that a rule oversight. It is reasonable to assume that, unless otherwise stated in the rules, a character's effects would travel with them, regardless of the mode of transportation.

There's a lot of rules that we just assume. There are no rules about what kind of nutrition a creature must eat, just that they must eat. There's no rule that says that a dropped object falls to the ground, but we take it for granted it does, short of magical items like an Unmovable Rod. The rules are meant to lean heavily on common sense.

That said, if a spell or ability allowed additional targets, it'd definitely call it out in the spell text. For example, see [Teleport](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/teleport), where you can transport up to eight willing creatures of your choice. It even goes further to say you can't target an object held by an unwilling creature.

Second, you can't generally use a spell or ability on an enemy without some sort of opposed roll or ability check, unless a rule specifically says otherwise. Any spell or spell-like ability that has any potential to affect additional targets will state what conditions must be met to affect those additional targets. If the Balor could relocate unwilling victims, there'd have to be a corresponding check, and it would be called out, or a specific exemption from this general rule.

I generally agree that there's some wiggle room for interpretation of some spells and other rules, but an important aspect here is that a player's agency shouldn't be violated without at least a chance to fight back. If I were to allow this to happen, there'd be at least a grapple check to have the Balor grab the target, and then (likely) a Wis save to resist the ability.

Without any rules to fairly arbitrate player agency, it wouldn't make sense to just let the Balor have their way, which could include things like teleporting up 120 feet with a victim, grabbing on to a ledge, then letting go, doing substantial damage in the process, all with no chance to save or avoid the damage.

I'd also say that this would become overpowered in the Balor's favor, allowing them to kill far easier than simple melee attacks. After all, that's up to 12d6 damage you can inflict every other turn while the characters helplessly splat on the ground. The players would have far more than a Challenge 19 on their hands at that point. Besides, Balors are already quite challenging to kill without having a cheap tactic like that at their disposal.

Answer (score 1):

## **Well, no.**

A passenger of any sort does not count as gear or equipment, so therefore the Balor would not be able to teleport along with an enemy.

Comment: Welcome to RPGSE. This is a start of a good answer. Please check out the [Tour], [Help], [Ask] and [Answer] for more guidance on what makes a good supported answer.  This message is brought to you by thing01 